# C++: Create new objects in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a recursive function where I want to push newly created objects into a vector (the vector is passed by reference throughout the recursion).

But after the recursion has finished I need the objects to still be there and not getting deleted because they are local variables. How do I achieve this?

Here's my code (base_pair is a simple struct containing nothing but 2 integers), the exit condition is missing at the moment, I will implement it later:

```
void Nussinov::traceback (int row, int col, std::vector< base_pair_type>& base_pairs, int dp_matrix[][_sequence.size()]){
    if(dp_matrix[row+1][col-1] == dp_matrix[row][col]){
        base_pair_type base_pair = {row,col};
        base_pairs.push_back(base_pair);
        traceback(row+1, col-1, base_pairs, dp_matrix);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the objects on the stack?

Comment: When all the recursions are done and if you still have access to the vector then you should be able to access all it's elements. Please provide a code sample to show what you are really doing.

Comment: I agree with @arunmoezhi. [`std::vector::push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) copies or moves the parameter that you pass it. Since it doesn't store a reference (i.e., to the stack variable), the vector should still be populated when the recursion completes.

Comment: A copy of the object `base_pair` will be in `base_pairs` at `base_pairs.back()`, what exactly isn't working correctly?

Comment: Last thing, is `declype(_sequence)::size()` constexpr? Because otherwise you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: oh okay thank you, I didn't know it makes a copy :) so I do not need to worry about having an empty vector after the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea to me. std::vector::push_back will make a copy of the local variable so it doesn't matter if the local variable is deleted. [I tried it out](http://ideone.com/6gYmXP) and it seemed to work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<int, int> int_pair;
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > int_matrix;

void traceback(int row,
               int col,
               std::vector<int_pair>& base_pairs,
               int_matrix& dp_matrix ){
  // bounds checking?

  if(dp_matrix[row+1][col-1] == dp_matrix[row][col]){
    int_pair base_pair = {row,col};
    base_pairs.push_back(base_pair);
    traceback(row+1, col-1, base_pairs, dp_matrix);
    return;
  }
}

int main() {
  int_matrix dp_matrix{{4,3,2,1},
                       {3,2,1,1},
                       {2,1,2,3},
                       {0,2,3,4}};
  std::vector<int_pair> base_pairs;
  traceback(0, 3, base_pairs, dp_matrix);
  for (auto& pair : base_pairs)
    std::cout << pair.first << "," << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```